# Group same attributes on xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML file as following and I want to Group the books based on the published year and    count the number of books for each year. sort the result by ascending order.

```
<body>
  <outline text="A">
    <outline text="Abelson, Harold" author="Harold Abelson" title="Struktur und Interpretation von Computerprogrammen. Eine Informatik-Einführung" publisher="Springer Verlag" isbn="3540520430" year="1991"/>
    <outline text="Abrahams, Paul W." author="Paul W. Abrahams" title="Tex for the Impatient" publisher="Addison-Wesley Pub Co" isbn="0201513757" year="2000"/>
  </outline>
  <outline text="B">
    <outline text="Bach, Fred" author="Fred Bach" title="UNIX Handbuch zur Programmentwicklung" publisher="Hanser Fachbuchverlag" isbn="3446151036"/>
    <outline text="Bach, Maurice J." author="Maurice J. Bach" title="Design of the UNIX Operating System" publisher="Prentice Hall PTR" isbn="0132017997" year="1986"/>
  </outline>
</body>
```

Here is the excepted output

```
    <p> Group by Year </p>
    <table border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="yellow">
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Number</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1963</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1966</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
```

Here is my code:

```
<xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:copy>
      <table border="1">     
        <tr bgcolor="Yellow">
            <th class="cell"><span> Year </span></th>
            <th class="cell"><span> Count </span></th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="outline"/>
      </table>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:key  name="groupbyyear"  match="outline" use="@year"/)/>
   <xsl:template match="outline/outline">
    <tr>
      <xsl:sort select="year" order="ascending" />
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm not sure how to use the xsl key function and what should I do inside the template after the key function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kOutlineByYear" match="outline/outline" use="@year"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
    <p> Group by Year </p>
    <table border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="yellow">
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Number</th>
        </tr>
     <xsl:apply-templates select=
      "outline/outline[generate-id()
                      =generate-id(key('kOutlineByYear',@year)[1])
                      ]">
      <xsl:sort select="@year" data-type="number"/>
     </xsl:apply-templates>
    </table>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="outline/outline">
   <tr>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="@year"/></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="count(key('kOutlineByYear',@year))"/></td>
   </tr>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document** (the provided one with small corrections to make it more representative):

```
<body>
  <outline text="A">
    <outline text="Abelson, Harold"
     author="Harold Abelson"
     title="Struktur und Interpretation von Computerprogrammen. Eine Informatik-Einführung"
     publisher="Springer Verlag"
     isbn="3540520430" year="1991"/>
    <outline text="Abrahams, Paul W." author="Paul W. Abrahams"
     title="Tex for the Impatient"
     publisher="Addison-Wesley Pub Co" isbn="0201513757" year="2000"/>
  </outline>
  <outline text="B">
    <outline text="Bach, Fred" author="Fred Bach"
    title="UNIX Handbuch zur Programmentwicklung"
    publisher="Hanser Fachbuchverlag" isbn="3446151036" year="2000"/>
    <outline text="Bach, Maurice J."
    author="Maurice J. Bach"
    title="Design of the UNIX Operating System"
    publisher="Prentice Hall PTR" isbn="0132017997" year="1986"/>
  </outline>
</body>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<p> Group by Year </p>
<table border="1">
   <tr bgcolor="yellow">
      <th>Year</th>
      <th>Number</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>1986</td>
      <td>1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>1991</td>
      <td>1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>2000</td>
      <td>2</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of the **[Muenchian grouping method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)**.

---

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kOutlineByYear" match="outline/outline" use="@year"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
    <p> Group by Year </p>
    <table border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="yellow">
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Number</th>
        </tr>
     <xsl:for-each-group select="outline/outline"
      group-by="@year">
       <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()" data-type="number"/>
           <tr>
             <td><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></td>
             <td><xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())"/></td>
           </tr>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </table>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), again the same correct result is produced**:

```
<p> Group by Year </p>
<table border="1">
   <tr bgcolor="yellow">
      <th>Year</th>
      <th>Number</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>1986</td>
      <td>1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>1991</td>
      <td>1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>2000</td>
      <td>2</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Use of the XSLT 2.0 instruction **[`<xsl:for-each-group>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-for-each-group)** with the `group-by` attribute.
2. Use of the XSLT 2.0 functions **[`current-group()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#current-group)** and **[`current-grouping-key()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-current-grouping-key)**.

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried to sort the table by year  <xsl:template match="outline/outline">
     <xsl:sort select="@year" order="ascending"/>
   why this is not working?

Comment: @Michael, You are welcome. In the `<xsl:sort>` you have forgotten to specify the attribute: `data-type="number"`. I corrected the two transformations to do the sorting.